# LTspice MOSFET turn-on issue

Tags: power-electronics

[image]

I defined the library for the NTH4L020N090SC1-D_2 MOSFET in LTspice. The MOSFET triggers when it's standalone, and I can measure a drain-source voltage of 530 V. However, when I converted it to a full bridge circuit, I can't measure the drain-source voltage. What could be the reason for this, and can you please help me? I have shared the circuit diagram below.[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what N003, N004 are, and the blue waveform is nearly illegible, but the sources tied to ground seems a bit problematic for making an H-bridge.

Comment: Try adding a small series resistance like 1 ohm to your gate drive voltage sources.

Comment: I added the 1 ohm series resistor as you suggested before the gate triggering, but there was still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is due to how you have connected MOSFETs U1 & U3 to their gate drivers.  The gate drivers PWM1 & PWM3 are connected to GROUND via the upside-down triangle symbol connected to pin SS of these MOSFETs.  The gate driver negative pin should **always** go to the SOURCE (S) terminal of the MOSFET, & not to GROUND.  The source terminal may be connected to the GROUND, but that is only if the power circuit requires this connection.  Yes, this connection of S to GROUND is required for U2 and U4, but **not** for U1 & U3.

I am also concerned with the connection to pin SS for the MOSFETs, please be sure that SS can be connected to GROUND if SOURCE pin voltage will go up to 530Vdc as you circuit suggests.  Check the datasheet if you are unsure.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help first of all. I did what you said, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Please post the new schematic, and include the waveforms that have the problem, and I will try to asssit.

Comment: [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcAvJ.png) [signals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNMpc.png) If my signals are like this, the circuit is progressing in nanoseconds. The circuit is very slow, and it gives an error after a while.

Comment: The signal on top is PWM1, and the one below is U1 Vds voltage. Also, there is no voltage reading across the drain and source of the MOSFETs below.

Comment: @nagihan - Hi, You wrote an "answer" trying to reply to *Fabio Barone*. That is not allowed on Stack Exchange. Answers should solve the original question, not reply to a person. A reply to an answer is either done in a comment, or by updating the question (if the new info is useful to others). I have converted your (non-)answer into a comment above. || If you want to include an image in a *comment*, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. Thanks.

Comment: https://r.resimlink.com/zgQcKlWLDv8q.png

Comment: https://r.resimlink.com/kS9DnemXEyN.png

Comment: https://r.resimlink.com/rVklZncgS.png

Comment: @nagihan - You seem to be posting links to an external image host. (a) Why are you using an external image host, after [I explained to you](/posts/comments/1811513) how to upload images and get a link for use in comments? (b) We see problems with some external image hosts, where images become unavailable in future, meaning that comments (or, sometimes Q&A) become useless when those externally-hosted images cannot be seen. That is why you should use the dedicated Stack Exchange instance provided by Imgur, as explained in the link in my earlier comment. Do you need help with using the site?

Comment: @nagihan May I suggest replacing all MOSFETs with the native LTspice element "SW", which is an ideal "voltage-controlled switch", then do your sims with that.  After the sims work as expected using the SW element, then you can replace the SW with some semiconductor model.  Try to eliminate the simple problems before adding extra complexity.